# O que é monkey patch?

Tags: terminologia

O que é monkey patch em programação e qual a utilidade e o risco de utilizar tal técnica?

Esse conceito varia de tecnologia pra tecnologia, de linguagem pra linguagem ou do que?

E um outro questionamento: por que esse nome tão esquisito?

Comment: Adorei a etimologia da palavra segundo a Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch

Comment: Link para leitura: http://blog.locaweb.com.br/artigos/desenvolvimento-artigos/monkey-patch-sim-nao-quando/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### O que é monkey patching?

O termo, que tem um nome estranho, se refere à quando você modifica ou estende o comportamento de uma aplicação em seu tempo de execução. O termo de forma popular é chamado de monkey patching, mas tecnicamente *dynamic runtime patching*.

O termo já era conhecido, mas o [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=Monkey%20Patch,%2Fm%2F06ff5) mostra que se popularizou com o Ruby, linguagem que permite o monkey patching de forma ridiculamente fácil. Veja:

```
puts "vnbrs".upcase

class String
  def upcase
    "Você foi trollado pelo monkey patching!"
  end
end

puts "vnbrs".upcase
```

O output:

```
VNBRS
Você foi trollado pelo monkey patching!
```

Perceba que o comportamento da classe `String` foi alterado em tempo de execução, visto que consegui sobrepor um método da classe.

### Por que é perigoso?

[image]
<sub>Sim... pode ser bem perigoso.</sub>

O Ruby, assim como o Python, tem a premissa de que o programador sabe o que está fazendo, então coisas como essa ficam mais acessíveis. Em linguagens como Java e C#, o processo fica um pouco mais restrito. Há quem diga que é uma proteção contra a maior ameaça de uma aplicação: o desenvolvedor.

Mas sim, monkey patching pode ser perigoso como nesse caso da `String`. Há alguns usos, como já citaram em outras respostas, para utilizar como workaround de algum bug ou comportamento estranho nas aplicações, mas que pode, se mal-executado, complicações maiores.

O [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#Pitfalls) traz algumas informações legais sobre os altos e baixos do monkey patching. Se ele for mal documentado, pode causar problemas:

1. Pode causar divergências de autualização quando o objeto que foi "monkeypatcheado" assume coisas sobre o objeto original que não necessariamente são verdade após as atualizações. Isso pode quebrar o monkey patching, e por consequência, a aplicação.
2. Se duas partes da aplicação tentam fazer monkey patch no mesmo objeto, o último que executar será o ganhador da corrida. Isso pode causar confusão.
3. Pode causar divergências entre o código original e o comportamento de fato, se o programador que está lendo não sabe do patch.

### Mas... monkey patching pode ser útil também.

Platão disse:

> Não há nada bom nem mau a não ser estas duas coisas: a sabedoria que é um bem e a ignorância que é um mal.

[image]
<sub>Quase tudo tem uma parte boa.</sub>

E por mais que tenha quem não goste, o monkey patching pode ser bastante útil para quem escreve testes automatizados. Um pequeno exemplo em Ruby de um teste:

```
# ./user_service.rb
module UserService
  extend self

  BASE_URI = "https://api.brasil.gov.br/"

  def fetch(username)
    response = HTTP.get("#{BASE_URI}/pessoas/#{username}")
    JSON.parse response
  end
end

# ./user_service_spec.rb
class HTTP
  def self.get(url)
    '{"username":"vnbrs","name":"Vinicius Brasil"}'
  end
end

describe UserService do
  subject { UserService.fetch("vnbrs") }

  it "returns the user" do
    expect(subject.name).to eq "Vinicius Brasil"
  end
end
```

Fazendo monkey patching na classe de HTTP, é possível criar um mock para os testes.

### Adoção

O C# tem algo como "monkey patching" através dos [Extension Methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), o que não permite modificar, porém adicionar comportamento. É seguro e amigável para o desenvolvedor. Não é bem monkey patching pois não te deixa mudar comportamento, mas sim estender, e a nível de compilação.

Em outras linguagens que não tenham um suporte tão claro para extensão ou modificação em tempo de execução, existe a metaprogramação e a reflexão, que podem dar algum tipo de flexibilidade nesse sentido.

Python, por exemplo, assim como Ruby, dá uma grande flexibilidade para monkey patching, vez que as classes são mutáveis e os métodos são meros atributos. Veja o exemplo em Python:

```
class Pessoa:
    def falar_oi():
        return "Oi!"

Pessoa.falar_oi()
# => "Oi"

Pessoa.falar_oi = lambda: "Não quero!"

Pessoa.falar_oi()
# => "Não quero!"
```

### Por que é chamado assim?

A etimologia do termo é meio obscura. Poucas fontes falam sobre, mas é comum ouvir que monkey patch vem de *guerrilla patch*, referindo-se à modificar o comportamento às escondidas, de forma sorrateira. Virou *monkey* pois *guerrilla* tem a pronúncia quase idêntica à *gorilla*.

> We talked about sneaking in and altering Python code at runtime; the
>   term Guerrilla Patching was used because sometimes dynamic patches
>   could interfere and conflict. Conflict -> Guerrilla warfare, as the
>   conflict was dynamic and depended on the terrain. [[fonte]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/235992/285228)

Answer (score 6):

É uma gambiarra que permite modificar uma aplicação quando ela está rodando ou fora do contexto normal dela. Ela é necessária para consertar problemas ou modificar um comportamento que a aplicação não permite.

É possível modificar os fontes quando se tem para resolver um bug.

Quando o software atualizar você vai perder esse patch.

Em sistemas como o Protheus por exemplo se faz muito isso, sem mexer nele fora do normal não consegue usar. Cada modificação que eles te mandam tem um problema novo e você que tem que consertar.

Comment: Não sabia que esses _patches_ no Protheus costumavam dar tanto problema

Comment: Oi Jefferson, é o dia todo todo dia fazendo isso, é triste.