# O que são fibers no Ruby e como usá-las?

Tags: ruby, terminologia, concorrência

Estava tentando fazer um proxy reverso usando WEBrick quando descobri que a versão que eu tinha instalado do WEBrick não continha os métodos necessários para fazer uma leitura "chunked" digna. Então apliquei o seguinte [monkey patch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285190/64969):

```rb
class WEBrick::HTTPRequest
    ##
    # Prepares the HTTPRequest object for use as the
    # source for IO.copy_stream

    def body_reader
        @body_tmp = []
        @body_rd = Fiber.new do
            body do |buf|
                @body_tmp << buf
                Fiber.yield
            end
        end
        @body_rd.resume # grab the first chunk and yield
        self
    end

    # for IO.copy_stream.  Note: we may return a larger string than +size+
    # here; but IO.copy_stream does not care.
    def readpartial(size, buf = ''.b) # :nodoc
        res = @body_tmp.shift or raise EOFError, 'end of file reached'
        buf.replace(res)
        res.clear
        @body_rd.resume # get more chunks
        buf
    end
end
```

Vi que ele usa `Fiber` para fazer a leitura em chunks, mas não entendi o que a classe `Fiber` é, nem o que o `Fiber.yield` tem de diferente de um simples `yield`.

Esse `Fiber` tem alguma finalidade com `threads`? O seu grande ganho é em usá-lo com `yield`s, ou tem algum outro caso de uso que não seja esse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Fiber` é uma classe da biblioteca padrão do Ruby que implementa um mecanismo de concorrência cooperativa, ou não-preemptiva. Vale lembrar que embora o contexto da pergunta seja sobre fibers no Ruby, esse conceito não é exclusivo da linguagem.

A diferença em termos gerais e generalizados, é que as threads usam um [escalonamento preemptivo, enquanto fibers usam um escalonamento cooperativo](http://wiki.inf.ufpr.br/maziero/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=socm:socm-06.pdf).

O fluxo de tarefas em uma thread pode ser interrompido a qualquer hora, e outra thread começa a rodar. Já as fibers, o fluxo do tarefas somente muda se você explicitamente pede para que mude, que é o `yield` em questão.

O grande ganho com fibers ao invés de threads, é que com threads o programador precisa ser hiper cuidadoso com *race conditions* e outros problemas similares. Já com fibers, o controle está na mão do programador.