# Como acessar um atributo ou método a partir de uma variável?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ciência-de-dados

Estou recebendo este erro:

```
Erro: " 'Series' object has no attribute 'medida' "
```

Tem alguma maneira de colocar uma variável no lugar do método e o DataFrame reconhecer o atributo? Abaixo tem o código como eu achei que funcionaria.

```
   def desc():
        lista_colunas = ['Pclass', 'Age', 'Parch', 'Fare']
        lista_medidas = ['mean','max','min','std','var']
        for medida in lista_medidas:
            for feat in lista_colunas:
                df_join[feat + '_' + medida] = df_join[feat].medida()
        df_join.head()
    desc()
```

Comment: No `pandas.DataFrame` não! Teria que fazer uma gambiarra ao estilo [monkey patch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285190/o-que-%C3%A9-monkey-patch) como sobrescrever em runtime a classe  `pandas.Series` para que incluísse o  método `pandas.Series.medida()`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode pegar um método / atributo qualquer de um objeto através de um string com a função *built-in* `getattr`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
# a linha abaixo equivale a escrever "soma = a.sum()"
soma = getattr(a, 'sum')()

print(soma)  # output = 6
```

Sem dados de exemplo, não consigo testar se o a lógica do seu código está funcionando. Mas focando na sua pergunta, você pode fazer a operação com:

```
df_join[feat + '_' + medida] = getattr(df_join[feat], medida)()
```

Comment: Acho que não bem é isso. Eu entendi que o AP quer adicionar um novo método a classe `pandas.Series`.

Comment: "colocar uma variável no lugar do método e o DataFrame reconhecer o atributo" me parece bastante com a descrição de um iniciante que quer usar o *valor* da variável `medida = "mean"` para acessar o método `df.mean` dinamicamente, mas percebeu que nem `df.medida` nem `df."mean"` funcionam. De qualquer forma seria bom se o OP voltar pra tentar esclarecer sua dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `eval` para fazer o que você quer.

```
def desc():
    lista_colunas = ['Pclass', 'Age', 'Parch', 'Fare']
    lista_medidas = ['mean','max','min','std','var']
    for medida in lista_medidas:
        for feat in lista_colunas:
            func = f"df_join['{feat}'].{medida}()"
            df_join[feat + '_' + medida] = eval(func)
    print(df_join.head())

desc()
```

**Nota** Cuidado com o uso do `eval`. Em determinadas situações onde o programa tem uma falha de segurança, pode ser perigoso o uso deste. Imagine que neste pequeno script seja possível a inserção de valor para `func`. Caso uma pessoa mal intensionada insira `select * from table` ou apenas `1/0`, ou outra coisa; o script poderia lançar uma exceção, apagar arquivos, elevar a utilização da CPU em 100% ou outro problema.