# Por que ter várias partes do mesmo módulo em vários arquivos?

Tags: ruby, modularização

Estava analisando o código de alguns projetos feitos em Ruby e uma coisa me chamou a atenção:

Sei que no Ruby, módulos podem conter constantes, métodos, classes e até mesmo outros módulos. Mas o que me chamou a atenção foi que em vários desses projetos, haviam vários arquivos com o mesmo módulo.

**Exemplo:**

**arquivo_1.rb**

```
module A
  def metodo_a
    # IMPLEMENTAÇÂO
  end

  def metodo_b
    # IMPLEMENTAÇÂO
  end
end
```

**arquivo_2.rb**

```
 module A
  CONTANSTE = "VALOR DA CONSTANTE"

  def metodo_c
    # IMPLEMENTAÇÂO
  end

  def metodo_d
    # IMPLEMENTAÇÂO
  end
end
```

Algumas vezes isso se repetia por 5 ou mais arquivos, o mesmo módulo, o mesmo padrão.
Fiz algumas pesquisas mas infelizmente não encontrei nada que me desse a resposta.

Então gostaria de saber quais as vantagens e desvantagens de se separar o mesmo módulo em arquivos diferentes, se não há a possibilidade de isso gerar algum tipo de "conflito" e se é comum esse tipo de separação, ao invés de tudo em um arquivo só?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ruby é como *jazz*](https://twobithistory.org/2017/11/19/the-ruby-story.html) - há uma liberdade radical para o programador, que vem com seus prós e contras. Essa [filosofia de liberdade](https://www.artima.com/articles/the-philosophy-of-ruby) é um dos pilares da linguagem, cunhada pelo criador, Yukihiro Matsumoto.

Uma dessas liberdades é a que você citou. Módulos (também classes pois são módulos) podem ser redefinidos em múltiplos arquivos, tal que:

```
# arquivo1.rb
module Matematica
  def self.soma(a, b)
    a + b
  end
end

# arquivo2.rb
module Matematica
  def self.soma(a, b)
    a - b
  end
end

# irb
Matematica.soma(1, 2)
# => -1
```

Essa redefinição nem precisa ser em arquivos diferentes, e segue o princípio do [monkey patching em Ruby](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285190/o-que-%C3%A9-monkey-patch). Isso pode te ajudar a organizar seu projeto, mas se você não sabe realmente como isso funciona, pode gerar comportamentos indesejados ao sobrescrever métodos como no exemplo abaixo.

A falta de visibilidade é o maior contra, pois quando se abre um arquivo `matematica.rb`, espera-se ver toda a definição do módulo `Matematica`, e não que se tenha algo perdido em algum outro arquivo.

O que se quer alcançar ao definir o mesmo módulo em diferentes arquivos é diminuir o tamanho de um arquivo que está ficando, como a comunidade chama, [gordo](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/skinny-controllers-skinny-models). Uma forma melhor de se fazer isso é usando um [mixin](https://blog.appsignal.com/2021/01/13/using-mixins-and-modules-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html), algo bem comum no Ruby. Um exemplo:

```
# matematica.rb
module Matematica
  extend Soma
  extend Subtracao
end

# matematica/soma.rb
module Matematica::Soma
  def soma(a, b)
    a + b
  end
end

# matematica/subtracao.rb
module Matematica::Subtracao
  def subtracao(a, b)
    a - b
  end
end

# irb
Matematica.soma 1, 2
# => 2

Matematica.subtracao 1, 2
# => -1
```

O exemplo acima é pequeno, mas imagine que nos "módulos internos" teríamos muita lógica, porém dentro de seu próprio contexto. E a API fica no módulo central, `Matematica`, chamando os módulos internos.

Voltando pra filosofia de liberdade, o programador ainda pode fazer besteira, como sobrescrever algo sem querer. E a vantagem é se quero saber o que tem dentro de `Matematica`, simplesmente abro o módulo e vejo tudo que ele está estendendo, evitando código espalhado.