# Teoria: self-modifying code somente é possivel em linguagens interpretadas?

Tags: terminologia, teoria-da-computação, metaprogramação

Disclaimer: Essa é uma pergunta referente a teoria da computação, não há códigos apenas duvidas sobre o conceito de ***Self-Modify***

---

***Self-Modify*** como o próprio nome já diz é quando um programa consegue modificar seu próprio código durante a execução.

Em linguagens como Python / Ruby / Javascript é possível realizar Self-Modify facilmente.

Mas seria possível realizar Self-Modify em um programa já compilado ? Ou isso é uma características exclusiva do ***Just-in-Time***

Aliás aproveitando o gancho Self-Modify é a mesma coisa de [Monkey-Patch](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285190/o-que-%C3%A9-monkey-patch) ?

Comment: Não na intenção de responder, mas de adiantar o assunto: um programa executável não é nada mais do que uma sequência de bytes. Nada impede do arquivo modificar seu original alterando estes bytes (salvo alguma permissão de arquivo, claro) para que se efetive na próxima execução, seja em que linguagem for (ai depende muito de como o OS lida com isso). Na própria instância rodando na memória, também depende muito do que cada OS permite, mas a analogia ao arquivo é a mesma. Provavelmente você vai modificar partes que não estão em execução naquele momento.

Comment: Outro cenário possível: em máquinas que tem um runtime (como Harbour, C# quando não é compilado nativo, acredito que Java também não deva ter dificuldade nisso, entre outras) você teria até a possibilidade de carregar e descarregar código pré-compilado até dinamicamente (em Harbour dá, é bem simples, inclusive pode substituir funções existentes e "devolver" o controle pras originais ao descarregar) - ou compilar novo trecho de código em runtime e executar. Aí já não é "auto modificação", mas é um "auto adendo", por assim dizer. Estaria mais pro Monkey-patch que mencionou.